# C++ | How to make a vector which contains multiple objects of different classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, game-engine

I am trying to code my first game engine in C++ which will be like how Unity's scripting works. I am trying to make a component system. Here is my problem:

I want to have a vector containing my component since I will maybe need to add some dynamically. Where the problem happens is when I want to add derived class of my Component class. Here is an example:

```
std::vector<Component*> components;
```

With this line I cannot do this (which I would love to be able to do):

```
gameObject.GetComponent<TextRenderer>().text [...]
```

I still need to learn a lots and sincerely I do not understand totally the part of this (I don't understand templates and can't find a good tutorial) code but here is my GetComponent function:

```
template<typename T>
inline T* GetComponent()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++)
        if (typeid(components[i]) == typeid(T))
        {
            std::cout << "Found Component." << std::endl;
            return (T*) &components[i];
        }
}
```

This function does not works it return nothing and/or have conversion problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. You're saying that you wrote this `GetComponent` function, but you "do not understand it"? Setting all of this aside, the shown code exhibits several programming practices that are generally considered to be bad, and error-prone. The shown code should be rewritten to correctly use polymorphism and virtual functions.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik - Wich code are you talking about exactly? Only the part where I show my **GetComponent** function or all of the code I have showed? Thx for your answer btw.

Comment: "I do not understand this part of my code but here is my GetComponent function." This means: "Here's my code, but I don't understand it". I wasn't sure how to unpack this. Even if "this part of my code" was something else, I can't quite square the concept of someone not understanding some code they wrote. I suppose this happens if you go back to some that was written a long time ago and one forget what it's supposed to do, and is trying to remember what the heck it was. But this isn't the case here?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No I wrote this recently. Well, I am very knew to the concept of template I started with C# and C++ has some things that I don’t understand and unfortunately templates are one of them. Let me rephrase. I don’t understand the parts with templates. The function return a **TextRenderer** which I can’t read because it is equal to null but I can’t understand why. I’m sorry if I am not clear and thank you for your time.

Comment: But you wrote "the part with templates"? What specifically don't you understand? As I mentioned, at first, the shown approach is somewhat error prone, and is not a good programming practice, so it's not surprising to see this attempt at manually hacking together what should be properly implemented via polymorphism, failing for some unclear reason. Unfortunately it's difficult to determine why, without a [mre], that anyone can cut/paste, ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce your issue. There could be many reasons.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok thank. I will try to rewrite my code using polymorphism. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that C-style conversion is undefined behavior.

As far as I know, all the component class(like SpriteRenderer, Rigidbody and so on) derive from `Component` in Unity. So we can use `dynamic_cast` which offers safe downcasting. If the casting succeeds it returns a valid pointer otherwise `nullptr`.

Here's an example of how I'd implement it.

```cpp
template<typename T>
inline T* GetComponent()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++)
    {
        T* downcasted = dynamic_cast<T>(components[i]);
        if (downcasted)
        {
            std::cout << "Found Component." << std::endl;
            return downcasted;
        }
    }
    return nullptr; // Unity's GetComponent returns null when not found
}
```

And please also note that `dynamic_cast` is relatively slow, just in case you care about the performance really seriously.